# Как провести проверку в словаре, и если нету объекта в нём то добавить, а если есть то удалить

Tags: python, словарь

Допустим словарь **recipes[]**. Как мне его проверить?

Не знаю, как точно объяснить сам не очень понимаю. Ситуация такая, мне дали скелет, и сказали к под него написать класс. И что бы при активации скелета, выдавало во такой список.

Тут снизу вверх, 4 строка, должен быть 1 "cake":
[![][1]][1]

Я сделал класс под скелет. Открыл его и у меня почему то 2 "cake"

[![2 "cake"][2]][2]

Рецепты берутся из скелета. Скелет трогать нельзя. Класс в котором я должен работать Bakery. Словарь сам находиться в классе Bakery. Словарь называется " self.recipes " . Рецепты(названия) добавляются в словарь через скелет. Всего класса 3. Мне разрешено трогать только класс Bakery.

Comment: Какого объекта в словаре нет? Приведите пример словаря и двух операций, когда есть нужный "объект" и когда его нет и что произойдет со словарями.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
recipes = []

if 'объект' in recipes:
    recipes.pop(recipes.index('объект'))
else: 
    recipes.append('объект')

print(recipes)

if 'объект' in recipes:
    recipes.pop(recipes.index('объект'))
else: recipes.append('объект')

print(recipes)
```

---

**Update**

> Ведь у меня словарь.

```
recipes = {}

if recipes.get('объект', None) is None:
    recipes['объект'] = 'value объект'
else:
    recipes.pop('объект')
   
print(recipes)

if recipes.get('объект', None) is None:
    recipes['объект'] = 'value объект'
else:
    recipes.pop('объект')

print(recipes)
```

Comment: Нет не получается. Ведь у меня словарь. А в словаре нету append. :(

Comment: @Ar1kato добавил обновление.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if 'объект' in recipes:
    del recipes['объект']
else:
    recipes['объект'] = 'value объект'
```